# Do HTTP clients send request bodies to the server even if the server returns a redirect (3XX)?

Tags: node.js, http, express, upload

I'm currently building an node.js express web service that receives client uploads (potentially large files). I have an endpoint (let's call it FOO) that returns a redirect for every request, telling the client where to upload data (let's call that url DEST). I'm worried that the client will send the data in the body of the request to FOO, even though FOO is guaranteed to redirect. I realize that the endpoint FOO can ignore the data in the request body, however I'm worried that the client is uploading the data twice. Once to FOO, and once to DEST.

Does anyone know if this is consistent with how HTTP clients behave?

If so, is there a way to prevent HTTP clients from uploading twice?

Answer (score 0):

By default in node v0.10.x or newer, streams start out paused so there is no data flowing. So you can immediately send the redirect and very little to no body data is transferred to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not exactly sure that completely answers my question (and perhaps I should be more explicit?). Some clarification, I'm wondering if it's possible to signal to the client to not send any data to the server. Is such a thing possible or is it just the nature of HTTP to upload the body?

Comment: HTTP is layered on top of TCP. So unless you start reading from the HTTP request stream in node, the TCP stack will appropriately apply backpressure, telling the client to stop sending data (with TCP NAK messages). Just try what I suggested and it should work for you.